# html selector using predicate of predicate

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

[image]

I'm working with puppeteer , I want to select a tr by looking for  a td with a specific title name.

I tried:

```
const targetPage = page;
const td = 'td[title="18to22"]';  
const td1 = await waitForSelectors([[td]], targetPage, timeout);

async function waitForSelectors(selectors, frame, timeout) {
  for (const selector of selectors) {
    try {
      return await waitForSelector(selector, frame, timeout);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  throw new Error(
    "Could not find element for selectors: " + JSON.stringify(selectors)
  );
}
```

which works. Now I want to get the parent row (tr)

How do I do this?

Comment: you are being mysterious about your `waitForSelectors` method (which I suppose is your own implementation as it is not part of the official API). anyway, selecting parent elements has no connection with the above code fragment. I shared a possible approach below.

Comment: @theDavidBarton, I updated the question with the code for waitForSelectors. It comes from the puppeteer script I downloaded using the devtools recorder tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve it purely with CSS selectors ([`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) "has" a poor support so far).
I'd use [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) togethet with [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) (I also recommend [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), but of course a `<td>` usually has a `<tr>` parent)

In the below example I retreive its `innerText`, of course you can use the node element as you need it.

```js
const parent = await page.$eval('td[title="18to22"]', el => el?.parentElement?.innerText)
```

Comment: Thank you, with regard to 'el => el?.parentElement?.outerHTML' , I'm not familiar with the question marks in the expression - What are they?

Comment: those are the operator characters for the mentioned [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). it helps to prevent `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'xy')` errors if you try to access elements that doesn't exist. in your use case you know that `<td>` has a `<tr>` parent for sure, so its usage is not mandatory, but a best practice.

Comment: I have a follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817918/getting-element-handle-within-table-using-puppeteer

Comment: I have another one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887958/puppeteer-intercept-request-with-login-button