# Getting element handle within table using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer

[image]

I'm working with puppeteer. I have a table as in the screenshot. I need to be able to click on the button under action in a row after selecting the row based on the name column on the left.

Based on [html selector using predicate of predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804280/html-selector-using-predicate-of-predicate)

I have:

```
const parent = await page.$eval('td[title="18to22"]', el => el?.parentElement?.outerHTML)
```

This does work and provides the html for the parent element but I want to get the parent element handle (https://puppeteer.github.io/puppeteer/docs/next/puppeteer.elementhandle/
) and then the last child element handle which should contain the clickable view button.

I tried:

```
const parent = await targetPage.$$eval(
  'td[title="18to22"]',
  (el) => el?.parentElement
);
```

This yields undefined.

How can I get the parent and ultimately child element handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot convert the already evaluated element back to ElementHandle.

I'd do the following to achieve what you need:

- get the content of the rows with `page.$$eval` (returns an array of strings)
- get the index of the row that contains the desired name ('18to22') using [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- now that you know the index you need to increment it with one number (as CSS's [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class uses numbers starting from 1, and not from 0 like regular JS arrays)
- so you can use the following CSS selector to grab the exact row: `tbody > tr:nth-child(${wantedRowIndex + 1})`
- ... the fifth column contains the button: `> td:nth-child(5)`
- ... the button seems to me an `<a>` element, so you you can add `> a` at the end of the selector to target the link you want to click
- finally you can apply [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) in the page function of `page.$eval`

Example:

```js
const rows = await page.$$eval('tbody > tr', elems => elems.map(el => el.innerText))
const wantedRowIndex = rows.findIndex(el => el.includes('18to22'))
await page.$eval(`tbody > tr:nth-child(${wantedRowIndex + 1}) > td:nth-child(5) > a`, el => el.click())
```